# Convert this For Loop into a list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

```
mp =np.array([10,
            -10,
             0,
             0,
            25,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
             0.0])

def transform_cbdeltas_to_rates(mp,r):
    dd = [0]*17
    dd[0] = r
    for counter,m in enumerate(mp,start=1):
        dd[counter] = dd[counter-1]+m/100
    return np.array(dd)
transform_cbdeltas_to_rates(mp,.5)
```

Correctly returns:
array([0.5 , 0.6 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75,
0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75])

Can I re-write this as a list comprehension or other shorter algorithm?

Comment: All great answers thanks. Got what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate

def transform_cbdeltas_to_rates(mp,r):
    dd = list(accumulate((m/100 for m in mp), initial=r))
    return np.array(dd)
```

I am pretty sure there is a `numpy` equivalent to accumulate stuff (e.g. [`numpy.ufunc.accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html)), but I am no `numpy` expert.

Answer (score 0):

Schwobaseggl has posted a perfectly acceptable answer so I will not extend theirs by much. `numpy` way of doing things though, which is indeed shorter and ever so slightly faster:

```
def transform_cbdeltas_to_rates_numpy(mp,r):
    return np.concatenate(([r],np.add.accumulate(mp/100)+r))

%timeit np.concatenate(([r],np.add.accumulate(mp/100)+r))
4.11 µs ± 58.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit dd = np.array(list(accumulate((m/100 for m in mp), initial=r)))
7.59 µs ± 189 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the `numpy` version:

```
mp =np.array([10,-10,0,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0])

def transform_cbdeltas_to_rates(mp,r):
    return np.concatenate(([r], (np.cumsum(mp.copy()) * 0.01) + r))

transform_cbdeltas_to_rates(mp,.5)
```

EDIT: Thanks to @Jacob Faib for pointing out the error. Works now.

Comment: Except that this does not match the expected output, `array([0.5  , 0.105, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.255, 0.255, 0.255, 0.255, 0.255, 0.255, 0.255, 0.255, 0.255, 0.255, 0.255, 0.255])`

Comment: It is also just as slow as the original non-numpy answer `7.09 µs ± 362 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

Comment: My testing gives 6.41 µs per loop, and actually 5.57 µs per loop if I don't do ```mp.copy()```, which is not strictly necessary.